# Connecting wireless router to sonicwall firewall

Tags: firewall, router, sonicwall, access-point, linksys

I have no idea what I'm doing and I don't have time to learn about it. I need a quick fix and am out of options so I am sorry if this post breaks the rules, I have done my due diligence in searching for a similar question but they all have the same result and due to my inexperience I am unable to find one that answers my question. It's really a series of questions...

The company I work for lost their sysadmin and has appointed me (audio engineer) to manage the network until further notice (ie forever until I fail, probably). I have accepted the position and risen to the occasion but have hit a brick wall (or should i say 'firewall')

We have a sonicwall NSA 250m firewall managing our net and everything else is networked with a bunch of passive switches. I need to hook up a linksys wireless router (wrt54g2) to one of these switches so I can enable wireless access to our network (and WAN). I have followed the instructions for setting up the linksys as an access point to a Tee. I am able to ping devices on the LAN but cannot access any shares or the WAN. I am almost certain that i have to create some sort of object (Access/Address/etc) in SonicOS to manage its configuration but have NO CLUE what is going on in there. Can somebody please assist me?

Comment: There isn't a tremendous amount to that.  If your Router-Turned-Access-Point has been given the correct IP address for the subnet you want it using, and you've turned off DHCP, and have wired up to the SonicWall via one of the numbered ports on the Linksys you should be good to go.  You shouldn't have to create anything in the SonicWall.  Can you link or post the instructions you used?  EDIT:  It may be helpful for you to post a screenshot of your IPCONFIG /ALL output from a computer that fully works and then from a computer behind the access point.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I have followed a number of linksys tutorials/questions but all have the same result; LAN but no WAN. As far as posting a link, I have tried dozens. Here is one example: http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/Help-seting-up-wrt54g2-as-an-access-point/td-p/324595

Comment: Now, I know DHCP is turned OFF on the sonicwall, but as long as I give the router and the connected device (laptop, phone, etc) a valid IP, that should not be an issue. Is that correct?

Comment: Okay so I am now able to work around this problem. I have a linksys E1200 wireless router in my office and I tried connecting it to the switch as an access point and it worked! Both routers have the same web interface, configuration menus, etc so I just tried to enable the same settings I had on the other router and the E1200 worked right off the bat. Either my wrt54g2 is buggy or I did something differently. I am now going to try it once more, step-by-step with the wrt54g2 so I can maybe get some kind of confirmation. Thanks for your help. I will let you know my results.

Comment: Be sure to use the switch ports on the WLAN AP. Don't use the routed or uplink port.

Comment: The 'Access Point' doesn't have a DHCP client on the switch ports (the numbered ports - as I said earlier and @TeroKilkanen mentioned again - use the switch ports only for this setup, not the uplink port).  You WILL have to give your 'Access Point' a valid IP, as you said.  If DHCP is turned off on your ENTIRE NETWORK -  its not running on the SonicWall and not running on a server somewhere - then yes ALL connected devices will need a static IP, not just the 'Access Point'.  I'd be surprised if the WRT was buggy in such a way that it otherwise acts normally but doesn't do this.